# Using alias for template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias

I didn't find any answer about this question :
I'm writing a template class DenseMatrix , the necessity of using the specification "Dense" before Matrix is because this class in in a hierarchy that have at the top the base abstract class Matrix from which derives SparseMatrix (from which derive al lot of class representing the different way of storage for sparse matrix, like CRS , MCRS, BlockCSR .. ) 
Now I wat make available for example in main function the possibility to instantiate an object of the class DenseMatrix using the simple name matrix (note that is not Matrix like the abstract base class) , so I remember that in C was possible used

```
typdef struct {

} name ;
```

then

```
name obj ; // instance of struct
```

I want obtain the same thing but in a C++ class (C++11 oriented) 
which is the best way to doing that directly in the header of the DenseMatrix class declaration ? 
P.S. during the defining of the method I always use DenseMatrix:: and not the alias

**edit** here the example , looking at the end of code

```
# include "Matrix.H"

template <typename Type>
class DenseMatrix ;

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DenseMatrix<U>& m )



    template <typename Type>
    class DenseMatrix 
                               :     public Matrix<Type> 
    {


           template<typename U>
           friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DenseMatrix<U>& m );

    //--
    //
       public:

           constexpr DenseMatrix (std::initializer_list<std::vector<Type>> ) noexcept ;

           constexpr DenseMatrix (const std::string& );

     //       constexpr DenseMatrix (std::size_t , std::size_t);

           virtual  ~DenseMatrix() = default ;

           Type& operator()(const std::size_t , const std::size_t) noexcept override;

           const Type& operator()(const std::size_t , const std::size_t ) const noexcept override;

           void constexpr print () const noexcept override ;

           auto constexpr size1()const noexcept { return Rows ; }

           auto constexpr size2()const noexcept { return Cols ; }

           Type constexpr findValue(const std::size_t , const std::size_t ) const noexcept ;

       protected:

           std::vector<Type> data ;

           std::size_t Rows ;
           std::size_t Cols ;

           mutable Type dummy ;
    } ;
// here ------\/ -------
template <typename T>
using matrix<T> = DenseMatrix<T>
```

thanks @R2RT it's what I was looking for ! **SOLVED**

Comment: Modern c++ prefers `using` over `typedef`.

Comment: yes I know ! but this is not my question .. my question is how to use it correctly and obtain what I wrote !

Comment: Can you give us a concise example of what you've tried to do so far please? You know a template class needs to be specialized for the template parameters to use an alias without any template parameters?

Comment: Great! At the moment I can only spot a missing `;` semicolon in your example of the `using` statement, and a lot of irrelevant code trying to show that. You are familiar with the concept of a [MCVE] when asking questions here?

Comment: So you want `Matrix` to be both the name of an abstract base class and an alias for `DenseMatrix`? How will the compiler know which you mean?

Comment: No ! pay attention I Wrote : Now I wat make available for example in main function the possibility to instantiate an object of the class DenseMatrix using the simple name matrix (note that is not Matrix like the abstract base class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right then you are almost here, but you have one `<T>` too much:

```
template <typename T>
using matrix = DenseMatrix<T>;
```

It's called template aliasing

> An alias template is a template which, when specialized, is equivalent to the result of substituting the template arguments of the alias template for the template parameters in the type-id

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias